# Rails tutorial chapter 3 Rspec test failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have been trying to follow along with the rails tutorial but I have been stuck on making the title slightly dynamic. Once I get to [this part](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#code-home_view_interior) and run

```
$ bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb
```

I receive the following error

```
Failures:

  1) Static pages Help page should have the title 'Help'
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_title("Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Help")
       expected #has_title?("Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Help") to return true, got false
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:27:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Static pages Home page should have the title 'Home'
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_title("Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Home")
       expected #has_title?("Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Home") to return true, got false
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:14:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) Static pages About page should have the title 'About Us'
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_title("Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | About Us")
       expected #has_title?("Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | About Us") to return true, got false
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:40:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.1826 seconds
6 examples, 3 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:25 # Static pages Help page should have the title 'Help'
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:12 # Static pages Home page should have the title 'Home'
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:38 # Static pages About page should have the title 'About Us'
```

This is what my Home, Help, and About views are like.

Home

```
<% provide(:title, 'Home') %>
<h1>Sample App</h1>
<p>
  This is the home page for the
  <a href="http://railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a>
  sample application.
</p>
```

Help

```
<% provide(:title, 'Help') %>
<h1>Help</h1>
<p>
  Get help on the Ruby on Rails Tutorial at the
  <a href="http://railstutorial.org/help">Rails Tutorial help page</a>.
  To get help on this sample app, see the
  <a href="http://railstutorial.org/book">Rails Tutorial book</a>.
</p>
```

About

```
<%= provide(:title, 'About Us') %>
<h1>About Us</h1>
<p>
  The <a href="http://railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a>
  is a project to make a book and screencasts to teach web development
  with <a href="http://rubyonrails.org/">Ruby on Rails</a>. This
  is the sample application for the tutorial.
</p>
```

And this is my Application view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | <%= yield (:title) %></title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all",
                                            "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

And my Static Page spec

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Static pages" do

  describe "Home page" do

    it "should have the content 'Sample App'" do
      visit '/static_pages/home'
      expect(page).to have_content('Sample App')
    end

    it "should have the title 'Home'" do
      visit '/static_pages/home'
      expect(page).to have_title("Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Home")
    end
  end

  describe "Help page" do

    it "should have the content 'Help'" do
      visit '/static_pages/help'
      expect(page).to have_content('Help')
    end

    it "should have the title 'Help'" do
      visit '/static_pages/help'
      expect(page).to have_title("Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Help")
    end
  end

  describe "About page" do

    it "should have the content 'About Us'" do
      visit '/static_pages/about'
      expect(page).to have_content('About Us')
    end

    it "should have the title 'About Us'" do
      visit '/static_pages/about'
      expect(page).to have_title("Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | About Us")
    end
  end
end
```

and lastly my gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.1.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.2'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your view like below(notice `=` before provide in the first line). Do the same for all your three views

Home

```
<%= provide(:title, 'Home') %>
<h1>Sample App</h1>
<p>
  This is the home page for the
  <a href="http://railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a>
  sample application.
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going to each page manually and checking the title yourself?

I pasted literally everything you provided into a project (I did the tutorial not long ago so I already had one set up with the `static_pages` controller) and all those tests passed. I would have said that you might have mixed up the filenames for your views, or the names in the routes file, but the content tests are passing so that can't be it. I guess it's possible that one of your files has been saved in the wrong encoding by your editor, or something else along those lines. Also check that you have in fact saved all your files before running your tests.

Also a quick note that `=` is NOT necessary for `<% provide ...` so you should probably remove it from your about view.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have forgotten to add the 'contact' page to your `routes.rb` file, like so:

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  get "static_pages/home"
  get "static_pages/help"
  get "static_pages/about"
  get "static_pages/contact"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

## static_pages_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Static pages" do

  let(:base_title) { "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App" }

  describe "Home page" do

    it "should have the content 'Sample App'" do
      visit '/static_pages/home'
      expect(page).to have_content('Sample App')
    end

    it "should have the title 'Home'" do
      visit '/static_pages/home'
      #expect(page).to have_title("#{base_title} | Home")
      page.should have_title("#{base_title} | Home")
    end
  end

  describe "Help page" do

    it "should have the content 'Help'" do
      visit '/static_pages/help'
      expect(page).to have_content('Help')
    end

    it "should have the title 'Help'" do
      visit '/static_pages/help'
      #expect(page).to have_title("#{base_title} | Help")
      page.should have_title("#{base_title} | Help")
    end
  end

  describe "About page" do

    it "should have the content 'About Us'" do
      visit '/static_pages/about'
      expect(page).to have_content('About Us')
    end

    it "should have the title 'About Us'" do
      visit '/static_pages/about'
      page.should have_title("#{base_title} | About Us")
    end
  end

  describe "Contact page" do

    it "should have the content 'Contact'" do
      visit '/static_pages/contact'
      expect(page).to have_content('Contact')
    end

    it "should have the title 'Contact'" do
      visit '/static_pages/contact'
   #   expect(page).to have_title("#{base_title} | Contact")
      page.should have_title("#{base_title} | Contact")
    end
  end
end
```

## application.html.erb

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
   <head>
    <title>Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | <%= yield(:title)%></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
  <body>
 <%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

## gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'

Becarful with spaces in the title